# Migrating simple website frontend and node backend to Azure Web App

Tags: node.js, visual-studio, azure, azure-web-app-service

This should be a lot easier than it has turned out to be so I wonder if I've missed something embarrassingly intrinsic to the Azure platform or Visual Studio.

I have two separate projects in Visual Studio (similar to this [link](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tomholl/2014/09/21/deploying-multiple-virtual-directories-to-a-single-azure-website/)) A plain HTML/JS/CSS website frontend and a node.js server backend which pipes it information. Everything functions as I'd expect it to within VS when testing locally (the node backend makes requests out to other resources in Azure and receives results back), but for the life of me there does not appear to be any simple way to publish this front and backend to a single Azure Web App because the app service will assign it's own ports to the server when it boots it up (effectively, without a static port # I can't knock on the backend).

Am I missing something plainly obvious or am I trying to do too much with the Web App service and need to break the backend out into a VM or other service? I've been able to compartmentalize the code as above in the link but I'm not able to ping or post anywhere other than the default landing page set by the root website.

Edit: Now I'm really wondering if I've made a wrong turn somewhere. A basic node app:

```
var http = require('http');
var port = process.env.port || 1337;
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' });
    res.end('Hello World on port:' + port);
}).listen(port);
```

returns

```
Hello World on port:\\.\pipe\a1f43073-e979-4a8b-b4ec-ec226b4760f8
```

Edit 2: Some digging has led to https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-Web-App-sandbox#network-endpoint-listening which is informative. However, it still suggests:

> Connection attempts to local addresses (e.g. localhost, 127.0.0.1) and the machine's own IP will fail, ***except*** if another process in the same sandbox has created a listening socket on the destination port.

So if I'm reading that right the process kicked off by my node server should create a listening socket on...something? Localhost maybe? I'll post an update if I make headway with this but advice and suggestions are still welcome.

Edit 3: I've solved my problem for the time being by wrapping my front-end into an Express framework project with routing triggering the backend operations, but this is far from ideal. I've not been able to successfully start a server which will listen on a socket in nodejs (a variety of error codes occur). If anyone has examples of functioning internal sandbox communications between apps (in the same virtual directory or separate virtual directories) that I could build against to make sure its not my environment that would be grand. I will post my own code when time permits.

Comment: Not sure what you mean about port assignments - web apps only support inbound traffic on ports 80 and 443.

Comment: What I mean is I can't find the Azure Web App equivalent to running a 'traditional' website on some port with a server it can ask for data listening on some other port for calls from the website, which is similar to the setup in the example I linked.

Comment: @4xle Do you wanna change default port 80 of your node.js server back-end to another one?

Comment: Not necessarily (though I think that would be the easiest way to accomplish what I'm trying to do?) From what I understand it's possible to have the server and the website hosted on the same Web App service but functioning independently from each other. If you will, the server works perfectly fine as localhost:8001 for local testing, and now I'm trying to determine how to direct the website to knock on the server once both are hosted on the Azure Web App service.

Comment: @4xle, what happens if you navigate to your website on port 80? Does that work?  Azure Web Apps only supports port 80 and 443 (for http & https) and external traffic can't access any other port.  The localhost tidbit you found is for when you have multiple sites running in the same App Service Plan. Then it's possible for them to talk to each other using the localhost url since they'll be sitting on the same VM.  If you're trying to get an external client to talk to your node app then you have to use ports 80 or 443

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for code similar to this:

```
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);

var server = app.listen(app.get('port'), function() {
    debug('Express server listening on port ' + server.address().port);
});
```

I'd recommend creating an empty node app and deploying it to Azure Web Apps. Then compare that to the app you're trying to port to see what the differences are

Comment: I'll give that a shot when I can.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. It doesn't allow for port changing, or listening on multiple ports. This simply allows a node app to listen on the port that the App Service mapped an app to (a required step, but one that doesn't solve the OP's problem).

Comment: Updated my question with the results.

Answer (score 0):

To redirect localhost:8001 to azutanga.com you can use nginx creating a virtual host. To use many port of a web application you can use Express to make many app objects as ports that you want to use. Or use cluster (https://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html) to share a TCP connection like java sockets.